# Python organize word in pairs of characters

Tags: python, function, text, input, printing

Does anyone know how to organize a word in pairs of characters using python?

Let's say I've got a random word. I'd like to divide this random word into lists of two characters. If the number of characters in this word is odd, then I'll add a Z at the end of the word to complete the last pair.

Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: So that the even and odd positions each form a pair, or what?

Comment: Please add some code of what you have tried. And also the format of input and output that you are expecting. Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: So you did not tried anything, but expect someone to write code for you...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
>>> a="sandeep"
>>> if len(a)/2 != 0:
    a=a+'z'
>>> a
'sandeepz'
>>> [[a[i],a[i+1]] for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
[['s', 'a'], ['n', 'd'], ['e', 'e'], ['p', 'z']]

>>> ["".join([a[i],a[i+1]]) for i in range(0,len(a),2)]
['sa', 'nd', 'ee', 'pz']
```

Answer (score 0):

Definitely:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> word = 'Hello, world!'
>>> list(itertools.zip_longest(word[::2], word[1::2], fillvalue='Z'))
[('H', 'e'), ('l', 'l'), ('o', ','), (' ', 'w'), ('o', 'r'), ('l', 'd'), ('!', 'Z')]

>>> word[::2]
'Hlo ol!'
>>> word[1::2]
'el,wrd'
```

Comment: How do you know this is what OP is asking for?

Comment: @yacc, how can it be not what the OP wants? It looks clear enough to me.